# click submit button every 4 secconds

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**how can i make automatic click per each 4 sec ?**

i want that submit button be clicked every 4 sec.
but its not work correctly

**my works :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>*BruteForce*</title>
    <script src="!Needs/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #form {
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #getHash {
            width: 440px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #length {
            text-align: center;
        }

        #boxContent {
            width: 833px;
            height: 469px;
            border: 1pt solid black;
            text-align: left;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form" method="post" action="server.php">
    <span>Enter Your Hash (SHA256) : </span>
    <input id="getHash" type="text" value="" name="getHash" title="">
    <input id="length" type="number" value="" name="length" placeholder="Enter the Length">
    <input id="create" type="submit" value="create" title=""><br><br>

    <div id="boxContent"></div>
    <input id="btn" type="button" value="..." title=""><br><br>
</form>
<script>

    setInterval(function () {
        $("#create").click(function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#boxContent").html(("Loading ..."));
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "server.php",
                data: $("#form").serialize(),
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#boxContent").html((response));
                }
            });
        });
    }, 4000);


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**as you can see . im trying to make simple brutforce method
but its manual , i want to create a auto .
i used setinterval for every 4 sec . but it doesnt work . ? any idea?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Instead of **creating** click events every 4s, **[trigger](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/)** it!
- Use that `event` argument!
- PS: if you haven't already (not present in your code above...) You need to include also the jQuery library! `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

```js
const $create = $("#create"); // Cache your elements!


$create.on("click", function (event) {
   event.preventDefault(); // Use the `event` argument
   // ... other code here
});

setInterval(() => {
   $create.trigger("click");
}, 4000);
```

Comment: excuse me. what if i want to . after submit button clicked. then setinterval run. not when page is load

Comment: It all depends on what you need.  Start the interval if a variable is `false`, afterwards set it to `true`. Or, you could clearInterval(itv) before assigning a new one. The task is not clear to give you a specific answer on that.

Answer (score 2):

**add jquery library script before your script ex:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```

and try this it works for me:

```
setInterval(() => {
   $create.click();
}, 4000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute the same code that the button will execute every 4 seconds and if you want, change the button's style to look like i'ts clicked